# Navigating with arrow keys in vi is slow

Tags: keyboard, solaris, vi

I use rlogin to remote login from a Solaris 10 Sparc to a Solaris 10 x86 host. When using vi, navigating with the h, j, k, and l keys is very fast and smooth. However, navigating with the arrow keys is slow, with a delayed response and/or the cursor jumps to catch up. The two systems have essentially the same configuration. I know this isn't a lot of information to go on, but what might be causing the arrow keys to respond slower?

Answer (score 1):

Each time you press a cursor key, it sends typically three times as many bytes as h,j,k,l. (It could send more, if you happen to be using a modified sequence, e.g., shift-cursor-up in xterm would double that amount).  Also, the first byte of each cursor key is an <kbd>escape</kbd> character, and the remote host has to wait for the last of those bytes to be received before it completes matching them against the sequence for a given cursor key.